# Having problems with functions in Pascal

Tags: boolean, pascal, freepascal

Here is the code:

```
Uses crt;

Type 
  mang = array[1..255] of Integer;

Var 
  N, X, Y : Integer;
  A : mang;

  Procedure Nhap(Var A : mang; Var N : Integer);
  Var 
    i : Integer;
  Begin
    Clrscr;
    Write('So luong phan tu: ');
    Readln(N);
    For i := 1 to N do begin
      Write('Nhap phan tu thu ', i, ': ');
      Readln(A[I]);
    end;
  End;

  Procedure Xuat(Var A: mang; Var N: Integer);
  Var  
    i : Integer;
  Begin
    For i := 1 to N do write(A[i], ' ');
    Writeln;
  End;

  Function KTMangTang(Var A : mang; Var N : Integer) : Boolean;
  Var 
    i, j : Integer;
  Var 
    kt : Boolean;
  Begin
    kt := True;
    i := 0;
    For i := 1 to N-1 do 
      for j := i+1 to N do 
        if A[i] > A[j] then 
          kt := False;
    KTMangTang := kt;
  End;

  Function KTMangDX(Var A : mang; Var N : Integer) : Boolean;
  Var 
    i, j : Integer;
  Var 
    kt : Boolean;
  Begin
    kt := True;
    i := 0;
    For i := 1 to N do 
      for j := N-i downto 1 do 
        if A[i] <> A[j] then 
          kt := False;
    KTMangDX := kt;
  End;

begin
  Nhap(A, N);
  Xuat(A, N);
  if KTMangTang then 
    Writeln('Mang tang') 
  else 
    Writeln('Mang khong tang');
  if KTMangDX then  
    Writeln('Mang doi xung')  
  else 
    Writeln('Mang khong doi xung');
  readln;
End.
```

The boolean value KTMangTang and KTMangDX were supposed to work but they returned these errors:

Free Pascal Compiler version 3.2.2 [2021/05/15] for i386

Copyright (c) 1993-2021 by Florian Klaempfl and others

Target OS: Win32 for i386

Compiling 34.pas

34.pas(53,4) Error: Wrong number of parameters specified for call to "KTMangTang"

34.pas(28,10) Error: Found declaration: KTMangTang(var mang;var SmallInt):Boolean;

34.pas(55,4) Error: Wrong number of parameters specified for call to "KTMangDX"

34.pas(39,10) Error: Found declaration: KTMangDX(var mang;var SmallInt):Boolean;

34.pas(58,4) Fatal: There were 4 errors compiling module, stopping

Fatal: Compilation aborted

Error: C:\FPC\3.2.2\bin\i386-Win32\ppc386.exe returned an error exitcode

I tried not to use the "kt" boolean variable but it returned other errors.

P/S: I use Visual Studio Code with Free Pascal Compiler (32 bit). If anyone knows how to install the 64 bit Free Pascal IDE, please help me.

Comment: You use KTMangTang and KTMangDX in the `if` at the end, without any argument. Seems to be the cause of 2 errors at least.

Comment: I think if there is no argument, the compiler just considers it as TRUE.

Comment: If there is no argument, the function cannot be called, because you have specified that the function must be called with two parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared `KTMangTang` and `KTMangDX` as functions taking two parameters and returning a `BOOLEAN`. You have *called* them with *no* parameters. This doesn’t work. The errors in the compilation specifically tell you this.

Comment: Call the function with two parameters, an `INTEGER` and a `Mang`.

Comment: Do you mean that I need to delete the Boolean type of the function?

Comment: No. In order to be used in the `IF` as you have, it must return a `BOOLEAN`. However, it ***must*** be called as `KTMangTang(A,B)` where `A` is a variable of type `INTEGER` and `B` is a variable of type `Mang`.

Comment: Ah, I got it now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I strongly urge you to find some basic books or on0-line tutorials on Pascal programming.

Comment: Do you know the best pages or books to learn Pascal?

Comment: What works (or worked) for me may not work for you. You need to find the books/sites that make it most clear to you.

Comment: I really appreciate what you can introduce to me. I am in Vietnam, where are no books and just no good websites so I need your help.

Comment: If you are not behind a national firewall like the People's Republic of China, a search of any good search engine (I generally use Google when I don't use DuckDuckGo) using the search term "Pascal tutorial" or "learn Pascal" should get you useful results. I believe the FreePascal website even has a tutorial on the language, though I don't know how good it is; it is many years since I was learning Pascal.